# errorfds vs select return value, and select() returning immediately?

Tags: c++, exception, select, timeout, unix-socket

I came to maintain a piece of software that does:

```
  /*... init, setting timeout, etc ... */

  FD_ZERO(&set);
  FD_SET(socket_, &set);

  int selectRes = select(socket_ + 1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
  if (selectRes < 0) {
    throw IoException("Select: ", errno);
  }

  if (selectRes == 0) {
    throw TimeoutException();
  }

  /* ... then handle recvfrom, throw IoException if return < 0 ... */
```

IoException should cause the program to terminate. Timeout exception resumes operation. Passing without exception loops back. socket_ is a UNIX datagram socket (reading messages from another local process).

This program runs at very high priority (required to react to messages quickly) but it's expected to be idle most of the time, hanging on select()'s timeout waiting for incoming messages. Meanwhile, it seems like it sometimes hogs 100% of CPU time (without receiving enough messages to grant such behavior). The occurrence is rather erratic, never mind the program's high priority makes debugging it very hard (a small single-core Linux embedded system, everything else grinds to a halt).

I'm worried about the NULL in the errorfds position - is testing the return value of select() enough in this case, or may select() return immediately (with 0) if there's an error condition on the socket but errorfds is NULL, and keep repeating doing so every time it loops back to select()?

Or alternatively, what other circumstances, other than an avalanche of messages, could make select() exit immediately (or maybe wait in a spinlock instead of freeing up the CPU time)?

Comment: What's the value returned by `select` when it hits 100% cpu usage?  You should be able to observe it using `strace -p <pid>` .  Is there any code that might change `socket_` from blocking to non-blocking?  Is the `timeout` always a non-zero/reasonable value?

Comment: @G.M. There's nothing setting or changing the socket either way (I assume it defaults to blocking?). Unfortunately no strace on this platform (and regardless, getting a command prompt in that situation is a miracle). I might print out the return value of select() if that helps,